# Open struts2-jquery dialog when a textfield is focused

Tags: jquery, ajax, struts2

I'm using the struts2-jquery plugin. I have a < sj:dialog > that contains a textfield. I want that textfield to launch another dialog box when focused. This new dialog box should also be rendered as an < sj:dialog > tag. What's the best solution for this task?

Comment: can't you use the event associated with the field to do what you want

Comment: Yeah i tried to use the .dialog() function but my client debugger claim it's not a function. That function was working before i put the < sj:head /> clause. Now it doesn't, i figured struts2-jquery plugin has its own dialog function.

Comment: aha..that's why i am not a big fan of JQuery plugin, though its really a very good plugin but come with many side effects.hope some one have idea abt it :)

Comment: Best idea is to just use jquery as you would in a regular html page. Then you can just post html and the jquery community can help you very quickly. There are quite a number of struts2-jquery-plugin questions on here and very few have answers... simply it causes more problems than it is worth. BTW this is a problem inherent to _any_ ajax/dhtml tag library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you can try to use a `<sj:textfield>` and its `onFocusTopics` attribute to fire the focus event,
 so that the `<sj:dialog>` with the same topic in its `openTopics` would then open.

BTW you could not use `.dialog()` because struts2jquery uses `requirejs` to retrieve the required js library at runtime only if these's existing `sj` components on your page.

You can overcome it by including a dummy `<sj:dialog>` in your page, setting it's `display` style to `none`.